# Oracle SQL select query compare 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with these two columns:

```
USERNAME    EMAIL_ADDRESS
------------------------------
username1   username1@abc.com
username2   username2@abc.com
username3   username3@abc.com
```

The first column is the username and the second column is `<username>` with email domain along with it.

How can I compare the two columns using Oracle SQL to find if there are any rows where the `email_address` column doesn't have the correct corresponding username in the email address format?

Answer (score 0):

> find if there are any rows where the email_address column doesn't have the correct corresponding username in the email address format?

Presumably, you want:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.email_address not like t.username || '%'
```

This will return all records for which the `email_address` does not start with `username`.

You can try and match on the entire user name with an expression like:

```
where t.email_address not like t.username || '@%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the data you've presented you can use a regular expression to parse out your email address and then compare the USER_NAME to the user name in the email:

```
WITH cteData(USER_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS) AS
       (SELECT 'username1', 'username1@abc.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'username2', 'username2@abc.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'usernameX', 'username3@xyz.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'username4', 'username4@abc.com' FROM DUAL),
     cteEmails AS
       (SELECT um.USER_NAME,
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(um.EMAIL_ADDRESS, '[^@.]+', 1, 1) AS EMAIL_USER_NAME,
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(um.EMAIL_ADDRESS, '[^@.]+', 1, 2) AS EMAIL_COMPANY,
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(um.EMAIL_ADDRESS, '[^@.]+', 1, 3) AS EMAIL_DOMAIN
          FROM cteData um)
SELECT *
  FROM cteEmails
  WHERE USER_NAME <> EMAIL_USER_NAME
```

which returns

```
USER_NAME   EMAIL_USER_NAME EMAIL_COMPANY   EMAIL_DOMAIN
usernameX   username3       xyz             com
```

when run.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=13f8253f4a2df2b6b1dd563aff02b5d8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex

```
SELECT * FROM your_table where username_col != REGEXP_SUBSTR(email_col, '([^@]+)')

//regex ([^@]+) matches any string before @ character
```

Example [db fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c169f6b5f4e00815f343ee20f618eda4)

```
WITH  da(usr, eml) AS
       (SELECT 'username1', 'username1@abc.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'username2', 'username2@abc.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'username_odd', 'username3@abc.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'username4', 'username4@abc.com' FROM DUAL)
SELECT * FROM da  where usr != REGEXP_SUBSTR(eml, '([^@]+)')
```